# Personal Access Tokens Section Missing on Tableau Online

Tags: tableau-api

I just received a development site through https://tableau.com/developer that I am going to use to learn the Tableau API's. Unfortunately the Personal Access Tokens section is missing from the My Account Settings.  Which makes it a little difficult to begin playing with the API's.

Here is a screenshot of the entire Account Settings page where the PAT creation tools should be located, but they are missing.  Anyone have thoughts on why the PATs section is missing or how I can resolve the issue?  I've submitted a feedback ticket through the Developer Program site and posted to the Tableau forums.  No help from either up to this point.

Thanks in advance for the assistance!

[image: Screenshot of the entire Account Settings page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This became a known issue in the dev site when another change was pushed to the 10ax pod that also made PAT disabled by default. You can try this URL to force it to enabled until the pod is updated again. [https://10ax.online.tableau.com/?personalAccessTokensEnabled=true#/site/{YOURSITENAME}/home](https://10ax.online.tableau.com/?personalAccessTokensEnabled=true#/site/%7BsiteName%7D/home)

Then navigate to your settings.

Comment: YES!  That did it!  Thanks a ton!  I've been trying to figure this out for days.  Much appreciated!